# Generating band diagrams using Kronig-Penney model

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I'm trying to use a solution to the Kronig-Penney model to generate a band diagram.

Solution: $$\cos(ka) = \frac{3\sin(\beta a)}{\beta a} + \cos(\beta a)$$

I know I can do this graphically by plotting the solution to find the allowed energies but is it possible to analytically find the values of $\beta a$ for which $\cos(ka)=\pm 1$?

[image]

Comment: The question about the solutions of 

$$\boldsymbol\pm 1\boldsymbol= \frac{3\sin(\phi)}{\phi} \boldsymbol+ \cos(\phi)$$

is a Mathematical not a Physics one. Try MSE.

Comment: At a first glance $\:\phi\boldsymbol= (2n\boldsymbol+1)\pi\:$ are between the roots for $\:\boldsymbol-1\:$ and $\:\phi\boldsymbol= 2n\pi\:$ are between the roots for $\:\boldsymbol+1$. Note also that the function of $\:\phi\:$  in the rhs is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is a [transcedental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), which does not have closed-form analytical solutions. It is however easily solved graphically (as the OP notes) or numerically.